# How to split an alphanumeric string into numbers and characters together?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that there's probably a RegEx to use with string.split but I can't figure it out or find the answer.

Say I have a string where each alphabetic character is prefaced by a number:

2A3B12C, for example.  How do I split this into an array of ["2A", "3B", "12C"]
or failing that, at least get ["2", "A", "3", "B", "12", "C"]

Comment: Instead of using split you can use match with something like /([0-9]+[A-Z]+)/

Comment: I was able to use match with (/[0-9]+ | [a-z]+/gi) and got exactly the result I wanted.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Answer (score -1):

Char to integer is not that hard to write, so why not just parse it char by char: int value=0, digits=0, string="", value = value* 10 + digit - '0'; digits++; When you run out of digits, you collect letters String=string + letter;, and when you run out of letters, you send the integer and string to an answer container, reset your controls.